# How does isolating transformer protect from geting shocked

Tags: electricity

From what i know, isolating transformer makes it that you would have to touch both ground and phase cables to get shocked, but why exactly is that.
There should be some potential difference between phase (transformer output) and ground (that we stand on), and as long as there is this difference, the charge is going to flow, and conduct a shock.
Or do I miss something here?

Answer (score 1):

If you had one sweaty hand on the isolated circuit, and one bare foot on the wet Earth, there would be no path by which current could flow through your body, and return to the isolated circuit.  A (probably) trivial amount of current could flow because of the AC voltage, and (probably) very weak capacitive coupling between the Earth and the circuit.  But, I'm guessing that the capacitive effect would not be enough for you to feel unless the voltage was very high.

Comment: Isn't earths capacitance big enough to get required 40 mA going through body for at least a couple of seconds? Also what do you mean by "because of ac voltage"?

Comment: Think of the Earth, which I admit, is sort of big, as one plate of the capacitor, and the isolated circuit, which is not so big, as the other plate.  The air, and whatever other insulating materials come between them acts as the dielectric.  It's be because of the relatively small dimensions of circuit (assuming the wiring is all inside some kind of appliance), and the relatively large separation between the wiring and the Earth (as compared to the separation between the plates of a purpose-built capacitor), I would expect the capacitance to be very small.

Comment: AC, because a steady DC current can not flow through a capacitor.

Comment: Forgive me if its going to sound trivial, but lets say we have a voltage difference of -100 between isolated circuit and ground. Isnt the current going to flow until the ground I stand on is "filled with electrons" (same potential)?

Comment: No, we can assume the earth potential doesn't change. A current will flow until the isolated circuit reaches the same potential as the earth. How much current this requires depends on the capacitance between the isolated circuit and the earth.